Comma position when there are few words in quotes

A: You should not use this word to describe a built-in TV.
B: I didn't use it to describe a "built-in TV", and I don't think anybody would.

Should I move the bolded comma inside the quotes? If the quotes contained more words, would the answer change?

In direct answer to your question, no, the comma belongs outside the quotes. That goes for both American English and British English. I noticed a (now deleted?) comment to the contrary, but that was conflating the context of your example with how listed items in quotes would be comma-separated. When an expression enclosed in quotation marks is followed by a comma, the comma typically goes outside the closing quotation mark in both dialects. The comma is not part of the quoted text.

If you are working to a particular style guide then you should follow the requirements of that style guide.  Most style guides for British publications would place this comma outside the quote marks. The Guardian style guide says:

Place full points and commas inside the quotes for a complete quoted sentence; otherwise the point comes outside

However many for US publications would place it inside (mostly for practical reasons associated with the use of lead type).  For example Purdue University insists:

Put commas and periods within quotation marks, except when a parenthetical reference follows.

If you are not working to a style guide, then just be consistent.
